# What does it mean to enregister a variable?

Tags: variables, exception, compilation, try-catch

What does it mean to enregister a variable?

I met that collocation in the **CLR via C#** book. Here is the excerpt which uses the collocation:

> Over the years, I’ve used exception handling in different programming languages, different
>   operating systems, and different CPU architectures. In each case, exception handling is implemented
>   differently with each implementation having its pros and cons with respect to performance. Some
>   implementations compile exception handling constructs directly into a method, whereas other
>   implementations store information related to exception handling in a data table associated with the
>   method—this table is accessed only if an exception is thrown. Some compilers can’t inline methods
>   that contain exception handlers, and some compilers won’t **enregister variables** if the method contains
>   exception handlers.

Does it mean that in some programming languages it is impossible to declare variables in a `try` part of a `try-catch` block? Or does it mean something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [CA1809](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1809?view=vs-2019), **variable enregistration** is the process of storing a value (pointed to by a variable) in the CPU's register instead of other memory.

The CLR will consider enregistering up to 64 local variables as values stored in registers are accessed the quickest by CPU when compared to other memory like cache, RAM etc.

It doesn't mean you can't declare variables in try/catch block.

I think the book is simply warning about a possible performance penalty as some compilers may not consider enregistering variables if you have exception handlers.